# Authenticate with Azure DevOps using Managed Identity (MI)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity, personal-access-token

I am using a Linux self-hosted VM agent with the relevant tools installed to run PowerShell and Az commands.

- This VM has a user-assigned managed identity added.
- The MI has been added as a user to my ADO organisation.
- The MI has administrator rights to my ADO project.
- Az login has been run against the VM, to authenticate into Azure with the MI.

I would like to authenticate to Azure DevOps using the access token from the managed identity rather than using a personal access token. After authenticating, I would like to use the az devops and az repos commands, to automatically control ADO.

Previously, I exported a variable `$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` and used my [PAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_access_token) token, which worked fine. However, when using the same variable and pointing it to the access token variable for the MI. It fails...

This is my current command:

```
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource $mi_client_id --query "accessToken" --output tsv

$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = $accessToken
```

I have also tried these variations.

```
$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource $mi_client_id --query "accessToken" --output tsv
write-host $accessToken | az devops login --organization $ado_org_name
```

The error I get is:

```
Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.
```

I have also tried to solve this issue by setting `$accesstoken` to become a bearer token. It is still the same.
Another way I have attempted, is to output the `$accesstoken` value to a txt file and run `get-content` before the `az devops login` pipe.

Following the details from here, this should be achievable in some way shape or form...
*[Use Azure Active Directory service principals & managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops)*

I know the ADO REST API can be used and to put the access token into a JSON header for authorisation. But this will not allow the az commands to work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know that already: I recommend testing the ADO REST API first and then go back to the CLI extension if needed.

---

They wrap all tokens as Basic authentication:
*[azure-devops-cli-extension/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/bd34a6fd0658a15dadf6c09c7f6217ca5ffa662b/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/common/services.py#L63)*

And other parts of the code with similar code constructs.

To authenticate OAuth tokens, you need to use a Bearer token that is (AFAIK) unsupported by the CLI extension: *[Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0, 4. Use the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#4-use-the-access-token)*

---

The quality of the extension authentication parts is really low and the team developing extension is unresponsive. Thus, I recommend creating a support ticket through the official paid channels.